# Average corresponding rows of BlockRealMatrix objects using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an ArrayList<[BlockRealMatrix](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/BlockRealMatrix.html)>, each member of identical shape, and want to average corresponding rows of each member into a further BlockRealMatrix of n rows and 1 columns where n == # rows of any BlockRealMatrix member in the original ArrayList. 
Having started with 3 loops I managed to remove one loop by using streams to sum the rows of each matrix but would like to try and get rid of all loops and use streams throughout if possible. Thanks

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.BlockRealMatrix;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StreamAdder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<BlockRealMatrix> matrixHolder = new ArrayList<>();

        matrixHolder.add(new BlockRealMatrix(2, 3));
        matrixHolder.add(new BlockRealMatrix(2, 3));

        matrixHolder.get(0).setRow(0, new double[]{1, 2, 3});
        matrixHolder.get(0).setRow(1, new double[]{4, 5, 6});
        matrixHolder.get(1).setRow(0, new double[]{7, 8, 9});
        matrixHolder.get(1).setRow(1, new double[]{10, 11, 12});

        matrixHolder.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));

        BlockRealMatrix averages = new BlockRealMatrix(matrixHolder.get(0).getRowDimension(), 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < averages.getRowDimension(); i++) {
            double average = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixHolder.size(); j++) {
                average += Arrays.stream(matrixHolder.get(j).getRow(i)).sum();
            }
            average /= (matrixHolder.size() * matrixHolder.get(0).getColumnDimension());
            averages.setEntry(i, 0, average);
            average = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("Averages \n" + averages);

    }
}
```

Prints:

```
BlockRealMatrix{{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0}}
BlockRealMatrix{{7.0,8.0,9.0},{10.0,11.0,12.0}}
Averages
BlockRealMatrix{{5.0},{8.0}}
```

Comment: I don't think BlockRealMatrix is very stream friendly to dramatically change your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `matrixHolder.stream().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));` can be further improved by directly calling the `forEach` method on the `matrixHolder` list i.e. `matrixHolder.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));` or using a method reference `matrixHolder.forEach(System.out::println);`.

As for changing *all* the `for` loops to internal iterations with the stream API. put simply this is not a good problem in which one would say "the use of a stream would be good here", hence instead of trying to change all the for loops with the use of stream API, let's try to make this a little bit more readable:

The `for (int j = 0; j < matrixHolder.size(); j++) { ... }`  can be changed to an enhanced for loop to make it more readable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < averages.getRowDimension(); i++) {
     double average = 0;
     for (BlockRealMatrix aMatrixHolder : matrixHolder)
           average += Arrays.stream(aMatrixHolder.getRow(i)).sum();
     average /= (matrixHolder.size() * matrixHolder.get(0).getColumnDimension());
     averages.setEntry(i, 0, average);
}
```

if however, you insist on using the stream API all the way then you could do:

```
IntStream.range(0, averages.getRowDimension())
         .forEach(i -> {
             double average = matrixHolder.stream()
                                          .mapToDouble(m -> Arrays.stream(m.getRow(i)).sum())
                                          .sum();
             average /= (matrixHolder.size() * matrixHolder.get(0).getColumnDimension());
             averages.setEntry(i, 0, average);
         });
```